# Pattern extraction from CLOB data

Tags: sql, oracle

My string data looks like this:

'Hello world. Travelling from ABCD-123 to ACDE-234.'

I need to extract the values 'ABCD-123 to ACDE-234' from the above string. I was going to use regexp_substr but I wanted to check if there are any other ways or extract this data. Thank you.

Comment: There are quite a few ways to do what you want **based on this example**. However, you should explain general rules because - I presume - this isn't the only string you have, so ... YMMV.

Comment: Before you start learning to program computers, you must learn to formulate problems. What you described above is not a proper problem formulation. What exactly to you need to extract? The *verbatim* string of characters `'ABCD-123 to ACDE-234'`? Somehow I doubt that. But other than that, you gave us no information (rules) about what must be extracted from the CLOB.

Comment: Here are the rules:

Comment: What I am trying to extract is exactly 'ABCD-123 to ACDE-234'.  Anyway, the example string I gave in the question
is not exactly the same string for each row. To add more clarity, here are some examples.

String_fld
'Hello world. Travelling from ABCD-123 to ACDE-234'
'Verbatim extract this string. ACGD-345 to ACDG-432'
'No doubt about what I want to extract. ACGG-456 to ACHH-566. Hope this helps'

In each of the three cases above I want to extract the following
ABCD-123 to ACDE-234
ACGD-345 to ACDG-432
ACGG-456 to ACHH-566

Comment: The first letter in this pattern of origin and destination is always an 'A'. Each origin
and destination has a length of 8, the first 4 are letters, the fifth position is a '-',
and the last 3 positions are numbers.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using `regexp_replace` like in the sample below

```
with t(str) as
(
 select 'Hello world. Travelling from ABCD-123 to ACDE-234' from dual
)
select 
       regexp_replace(str,'.*.\from(.*)','\1') as "Result String"
  from t;

 Result String
 --------------------
  ABCD-123 to ACDE-234
```

Answer (score 0):

The below query will work for all 3 strings but not sure about performance and I couldn't find any simply method:

```
select reverse(REGEXP_SUBSTR(reverse('Hello world. Travelling from ABCD-123 to ACDE-234'),'[^ ]+',1,3))||' '||
       reverse(REGEXP_SUBSTR(reverse('Hello world. Travelling from ABCD-123 to ACDE-234'),'[^ ]+',1,2))||' '||
       reverse(REGEXP_SUBSTR(reverse('Hello world. Travelling from ABCD-123 to ACDE-234'),'[^ ]+',1,1))
from dual;
```